# Error running zsh installed with linuxbrew (homebrew)

Tags: debian, homebrew, zsh, linuxbrew

I have installed without problems `zsh` using `linuxbrew`:

```
brew install zsh
```

Now, when running `zsh` I get the error:

```
zsh: error while loading shared libraries: libgdbm.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But `libgdm.so.4` is already present in `~/.linuxbrew/lib` and I already have in both my `.bashrc` and `.zshrc`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Am I missing something?

I'm in Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` setting in my .bashrc. It must be:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

[More information](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/issues/54#issuecomment-36037173)